# HTML onmouseover doesn't work to show up text

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover

I'm trying to show some information on a picture when onmouseover/onmouseout event occurs. What I want to achieve is something like [this website](http://www.piercedfish.com) does on top selling.

My code is like this:

```
<div class="container" onmouseover="$('#info').css('display','block');" onmouseout="$('#info').css('display','none');">
<img src=...">
    <div id="info" style="display:none">
       ... some text ...
</div>
</div>
```

So div info block is initially hidden, but when mouse is on a picture I want the information
to appear on corresponding picture (with tint background on the image to see text well). But somewhat it doesn't work. I appreciate any suggestion how to approach this problem.

Edit: I forgot to mention that div id info is not exist in css. I'm not sure that I need to dynamically create rule and attach it to body. In addition, the reason why I choose to use inline because I need to show/hide text corresponding to the image(contain unique div id)that user put their mouse on/out. That means I have many div container and each container has unique div id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your way is wrong

try this one

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <head>
                <title>Horton Computer Solutions Home</title>

            </head>
            <style type="text/css">
            .container{
            width:100px;
            }

            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function over(){

            document.getElementById("info").style.display="block"
            }
            function out(){
            document.getElementById("info").style.display="none"
            }
            </script>
        <body>

            <div class="container">
    <img src="" alt="asdasd" onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()">
    <div id="info" style="display:none">
       ... some text ...
        ... some text ...
         ... some text ...
          ... some text ...
           ... some text ...
            ... some text ...
    </div>
    </div>



            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead inline `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`:

```
$('.container').mouseover(function() {
    $('#info').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('#info').hide();
});
```

And it's also better to use `show();` / `hide();` instead `css('display','block');` / `css('display','block');`

So the code will be:

```
<div class="container">
   ...
   <div style="display:none" id="info">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.container').mouseover(function() {
            $('#info').show();
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#info').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to make functions instead of just doing stuff in onMouseOver tag itself. It makes it very unreadable and you can simple make mistakes by using double qoutes and you would get syntax errors.

Second, what doesn't work?
Does it not appear? Btw, you can use $('#info').show() and .hide() as well. Does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
 <div class="out overout">
  <span>move your mouse</span>
  <div class="in">
  </div>
</div>

 <script>
  var i = 0;
  $("div.overout").mouseover(function() {
    i += 1;
    $(this).find("span").text( "mouse over x " + i );
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("span").text("mouse out ");
  });
</script>
```

visit here for [Demo](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

You should put that in a script tag, as shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp
Now you put jQuery in your html.

If you put it on the bottom of your page and do it like so:

```
$('#container').mouseenter (function() {
     $('#info').css('display','block');
});
```

and

```
$('#container').mouseout (function() {
     $('#info').css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv() {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#info').css('display','block');
});
}

function hidediv() {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#info').css('display','none');
});
}
</script>

<div class="container" onmouseover="showdiv()" onmouseout="hidediv()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your "onMouseOut" event on the div to display

this piece of code work

```
    <img src="" style="width:50px;height:50px;" onmouseover="testOn();" >
<div onmouseout="testOut();" id="info" style="width:50px;height:50px;display:none;color:white;background-color:black;opacity:0.7; position:relative;top:-50px;">
    bla bla
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testOn()
    {
        $('#info').css('display','block');
    }

    function testOut()
    {
        $('#info').css('display','none');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it replace image in onmouseover event. But won't work in internet explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>onmouseover, onmouseout test</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.png" alt="" onmouseout="this.src='image1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='image2.png'">&nbsp;
</body>
</html>
```